# Handling on load, on change via angular, jquery and web api

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, asp.net-web-api

I am binding dropdown select with ng-repeat.

```
<select onchange="ChangeMonth()"  id="month">
                <option ng-repeat="(key,val) in Months" ng-selected="val==ActiveMonth" value="{{key}}">
                    {{val}}
                </option>
</select>
```

On change i am calling a jquery function,

```
  var valueSelected = $('#month option:selected').val();
   var textSelected = $('#month option:selected').text().trim();       
 angular.element(document.getElementById('month')).scope().SelectedMonth(valueSelected, textSelected);
```

Based on selected value, i load the data on the form- which works.

Here is my angular function below:

```
$scope.SelectedMonth = <<angular code here>> -> internally does a webapi call to load data.
```

Question: I want to automatically identify the selected element and load the data on the form accordingly.

Essentially,call the same angular function on load and change in a way that ,the combobox is first filled in before actual load call happens?

Comment: Can you explain a bit better want do you want to achieve please? you want that selecting a value from the select you will throw your angular code?

Comment: In the dropdown, when it gets bound, say  -January, Month etc, the selected month is January,data don't get filled in, wherein when i do a switch from January to February, the data gets changed, i want to do a data fill in for january when loaded.

Comment: Any inputs will help?

Comment: Can you please set up a jsfiddle or codepen with your sample?

Answer (score 0):

Did a call to ng-init on the select dropdown and inside that function, i called the actual method function to get the return values.